# controller and initial value in TextFormField do not work

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use TextFormField to get stored value from Firestore and display it to user in it's (edit profile) page,with ability to change field value.

My question is:
how can i enable initial value(to get stored value) and controller to pick entered value by the user.

I read the document and i know i can't use both together,but is there an idea to allow textfield to get stored value and edit it in the same time?

```
            TextFormField(
                            controller: phone_controller,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration:   InputDecoration(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
                              hintText: phone,
                            //  labelText: phone,
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              String pattern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
                              RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
                              if (value.isEmpty || !regExp.hasMatch(value) ) {
                                return 'Please enter valid phone number like 01001234567';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          )
```

Comment: TextFormField( initialValue: "Your initial text value" ), You can set the it to your desired variables from the data source

Comment: Or if you are using value from controller:  do this TextEditingController tedController = TextEditingController()..text ="your init value from firestore"; then use it as TextField( controller: tedController )

Answer (score 2):

In your initState, you can set the initial value of the controller.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  phone_controller.text = 'phone_no';
}
```

phone_controller now has a default value;